# Flutter BloC state executed but the UI didn't change after the state changed

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-getx

I am using the Bloc and Getx for state management and routing. I have solved the problem of the Bloc is nested with different child with the route which causing the Bloc cannot be found/read if I change the route. Which the solution is wrap the GetMaterialApp inside the BlocProvider.

```
import ;...

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
      create: (context) => AuthBloc(FirebaseAuthProvider()),
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: theme(),
        home: const MainPage(),
        /*BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
          create: (context) => AuthBloc(FirebaseAuthProvider()),
          child: const MainPage(),
        ),*/
        getPages: RoutesClass.routes,
        // routes: {
        // verifyEmailRoute: (context) => const VerifyEmailView(), // not used
        // },
        // routes: routes, // switch to getx
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

But now the Bloc is running well. I use the Bloc for FirebaseAuth. I can do login and logout (the state is correct in logic. I'm sure because it was functioned properly if I didn't click the navigation bar to change route.) if I didn't change the page/view with the bottom navigation bar.

If I change the page/view with the bottom navigation bar and click logout, the Bloc state executed but the UI cannot be changed to logout state. The bottom navigation bar is custom and the routing of changing page is using the Getx to perform routing. using the Get.toNamed() function.

Sorry for my bad explanation. Below is my code for your reference:

```
import 'package:facerecognitionattendance/services/auth/bloc/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:facerecognitionattendance/services/auth/bloc/auth_event.dart';
import 'package:facerecognitionattendance/utilities/dialogs/logout_dialog.dart';
import 'package:facerecognitionattendance/views/profile/components/profile_menu.dart';
import 'package:facerecognitionattendance/views/profile/components/profile_pic.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart' show ReadContext;

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body({super.key});

  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const ProfilePic(),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ProfileMenu(
              text: "My Account",
              icon: "assets/icons/User Icon.svg",
              press: () => {},
            ),
            ProfileMenu(
              text: "Notifications",
              icon: "assets/icons/notification.svg",
              press: () {},
            ),
            ProfileMenu(
              text: "Settings",
              icon: "assets/icons/Settings.svg",
              press: () {},
            ),
            ProfileMenu(
              text: "Log Out",
              icon: "assets/icons/Log out.svg",
              press: () async {
                final shouldLogout = await showLogOutDialog(context);
                if (shouldLogout) {
                  if (!mounted) return;
                  context.read<AuthBloc>().add(
                        const AuthEventLogOut(),
                      ); // HERE
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope these will help for the explanation. Thanks in advance.

I tried to add the BlocProvider but does not work. Expecting the logout state executed and change the UI back to the sign in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `Body` widget should be a StatelessWidget in this example if you don't make use of the state, also Bloc handles that for you.
To solve the redirect you should wrap your code in a BlocListener to listen for changes in the state of AuthBloc. Here's an example:

```dart
return BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
    listener: (BuildContext context, state) {
        // Check here if the state is unathenticated
        if (state is Unauthenticated) {
          Get.toNamed(); // Your login or initial page
        }
    },
    child: SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // Your code here...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Also in BlocListener you can just listen to some changes in the state, like for example the authStatus, you can use the property `listenWhen` for that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank for the reply. The Body cannot be Stateless Widget since there is a line of this code 'if (!mounted) return;' The state checking I have wrote in the main.dart. Which is should be like if I logout, the main.dart will manage the business logic for showing the correct state.

Comment: I know your point of using the BlocListener because if the code of context.read<AuthBloc>().add(const AuthEventLogOut()); will trigger the BlocListener to check the current state and push the navigator Get.toNamed(). But the previous comment I wrote which says I have include the logic in the main.dart. Is it really need to repeat the code of the main.dart and put inside the BlocListener again? Is this the proper way?

Comment: Update - this answer is working. I am not sure can make it more shorter line in code or not. Thank for your help.

Comment: This is the correct way to create a listener inside your widget, a few lines are required to do so! You can call AuthEventLogOut() inside the dialog so you don't have to await for the shouldLogout and then convert the main widget to stateless.